# Is there anyway to use a user inputted class Item name to access the data in that item?

Tags: c++, class

How to access class data from a user inputted class name?

I set a variable `string a;` and when I try to return something like `a.name` or `a.price` it won't print the data. Say in the example below a user inputs `Z`.

```
Z.name = "Milk" ; 
Z.price = 2 ; 
Z.itemnum = 26 ;

string a = ""; 
int b;

while (a != "0") {
  cout << "Enter the item letter: " ; 
  cin >> a ; 
  cout << "Enter an item quantity: ";
  cin >> b;
  cout << "You got " << b << " things of " << a.name << endl; 
  cout << a ;
}
```

Comment: please revise your question and clarify your concern.

Comment: variable names have zero relevance in a running program. If you want to map names to objects you need to supply that mapping yourself eg with a `std::map<std::string, some_type>`. You are confusing "class" and "object" in your questions... if you want the user to select a class it will need even more

Comment: This will not compile. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @delimiter: Pro Tip: you can use `[mcve]` in a comment. It will expand thusly: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does not work the way you are thinking.  Variable names are only used in code, they are lost during compiling.  And you certainly cannot treat a string as-is as a variable name.

For what you are attempting, you need to perform the mapping of names to objects yourself.  You can use a `std::map` for that, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Item
{
  std::string name;
  double price;
  int itemnum;

  void set(std::string newName, double newPrice, int newItemNum) {
    name = newName;
    price = newPrice;
    itemnum = newItemNum;
  }
};

std::map<std::string, Item> items;

items["Z"].set("Milk", 2, 26);
// other items as needed...

std::string a; 
int b;

do {
  std::cout << "Enter the item letter: ";
  std::cin >> a; 
  if (a == "0") break;
  auto iter = items.find(a);
  if (iter != items.end()) {
    std::cout << "Enter an item quantity: ";
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << "You got " << b << " things of " << iter->second.name << std::endl; 
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "There is no item letter of " << a << ", try again" << std::endl; 
  }
}
while (true);
```

Comment: Received and understood.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how objects work.

`string a = "";`

is simply a string object that contains no other fields.  The only data it will hold is that data that is read in through the input stream when you do `cin >> a;`.

Now you could take `a` and `b` and assign them to `Z.name = a;` and `Z.itemnum = b;` and then do `cout << Z.name;` and `cout << Z.itemnum`